# Three.js italic font

Tags: three.js

for some reason I cannot make a font italic in three.js. I use below code for it which works well for setting font size or color, but italic just won't work.

```
var params = {
        material: 0,
        extrudeMaterial: 1,
        bevelEnabled: false,
        bevelThickness: 8,
        bevelSize: 4,
        font: fonts[0].font,
        weight: this.weight,
        style: this.style,
        height:(this.type==0) ? 0 : gravurDepth,
        size: this.size,
        curveSegments: 4
    };

    var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry(this.txt, params);
```

I set `this.style` via below line and see the values get set in debug mode

```
this.style = (this.style == "normal") ? "italic" : "normal";
```

Is there some special font I need to load like I guess for the bold case? There do not seem to be special fonts for Italic in the example/fonts folder..

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: Seems that indeed I need to add new fonts as I found in a sample on http://www.johannes-raida.de/tutorials/three.js/tutorial14/tutorial14.htm. Question then just is where to get those fonts...